# Create 1000 tables using script in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need to create 1001 tables, table names should be 0-1000 and each table has two double value columns called A and B. How do I create this many tables without executing 1001 `CREATE TABLE` queries manually? I am using Postgresql on linux.

Comment: What version of Postgres are you on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am sure there is a best way to do this, but you could generate the statements in shell script and then just load the sql.

Something like

```
#!/bin/sh
NAME="name"
COLUMNA="ca"
COLUMNB="cb"

for i in `seq 0 1000`;
  do
    echo "CREATE TABLE $NAME$i ($COLUMNA varchar(200), $COLUMNB varchar(200));"
  done
```

Then you just execute `sh script.sh > creation.sql` and load it with Postgres.